# Emberjs: can a property be computed over something that is not in the model?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, ember.js

I'm an Ember.js noob and was trying to figure something out. This is my ObjectController -

```
App.CommodityController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    addedToCart: false,

    actions: {
        addToCart: function(commodity) {
            this.addedToCart = true;
        },
        removeFromCart: function(commodity) {
            this.addedToCart = false;
        }   
    }

});
```

And this is my ArrayController -

```
App.CommoditiesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    inCart: function() {
        return this.filterBy('addedToCart',true);       
    }.property('@each.addedToCart')
});
```

The property `inCart` isn't evaluating. The thing is `addedToCart` is not in my model - I did observe that it worked when I tested it with something that is in my model.

Is it not possible to make it work with a property that is not in the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by doing this way.

`.property('@each.addedToCart')` will look at its own model i.e, the `App.CommoditiesController`'s model for the property `addedToCart`.

**You can only run `@each` on an array.**

If you want to be able to access the `App.CommodityController`'s model, then you will have to add it in a `needs` array.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
this.addedToCart = true;
```

To:

```
this.set('addedToCart', true);
```

Or you could also do:

```
this.toggleProperty('addedToCart');
```

**Reason**: directly setting the property doesn't fire off any change observers which is what drives the computed properties. Using set/get/toggle does. (Someone more experienced might correct me on this)

Comment: Thanks a lot Chuck - although this change didn't help. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide some more code so that there's context to what you're showing?

Comment: Well that's pretty much it right now - I just have html that has a button that triggers the addToCart, and another piece of html where I need to list all the items added to the cart, and I want to use my computed property inCart to do that. I'm just using a simple array right now as the model data - no Ajax going on yet.